# Generate a large number of HEX

Tags: python

I am trying to generate all 16^16,
but there are a few problems. Mainly memory.
I tried to generate them in python like this:

```
for y in range (0, 16**16): 
    print '0x%0*X' % (16,y)
```

This gives me:

> OverflowError: range() result has too many items

If I use sys.maxint I get a MemoryError.

To be more precise, I want to generate all combinations of HEX in length of 16, i.e:

```
0000000000000000
0000000000000001
0000000000000002
...
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Also, how do I calculate the approximate time it will take me to generate them?

I am open to the use of any programming language as long as I can save them to an output file.

Comment: Um...  a very long time.  16^16 = 2^64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 values.  Even generating a a rate of one value per microsecond — that's 1 million per second — that would still take 584,000 _years_ to finish.

Comment: Has someone asked you to do this as a joke? Seems equivalent to being sent to supplies for a long weight, or to buy elbow grease. What will you do with the file once you have it?

Comment: What is a doable size? i though 2^80 is breakable

Comment: If you're trying to break encryption, you probably want to apply much smarter techniques than brute-forcing all values.  Use a numeric sieve or something.  And use a high-core GPU to do whatever math you're going to do in parallel.  That said, breaking encryption is hard; there's a lot that even the NSA can't crack, even for smallish bit sizes.  SHA-1 was only cracked for the first time in 2017, and it took all of Google's hardware and several months (and several Ph.D's) to pull it off.

Comment: The file would be about 300 [Exabytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exabyte)

Comment: And I don't see the purpose of storing it as file. I mean you can generate any value or any subrange of that sequence on demand.

Answer (score 1):

Well... 16^16 = 1.8446744e+19, so lets say you could calculate 10 values per nanosecond (that's a 10GHz rate btw). Then it would take you 16^16 / 10 nanoseconds to compute them all, or 58.4 years. Also, if you could somehow compress each value into 1-bit (which is impossible), it would require 2 exabytes of memory to contain those values (16^16/8/2^60).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very artificial exercise. Is it homework, or is there a reason for generating this list? It will be very long (see other answers)!

Having said that, you should ask yourself: why is this happening? The answer is that *in Python 2.x*, `range` produces an actual list. If you want to avoid that, you can:

1. Use Python 3.x, in which `range` does not actually make a list, but a special generator-like object.
2. Use [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange), which also doesn't actually make a list, but again produces an object.

As for timing, all of the time will be in writing to the file or screen. You can get an estimate by making a somewhat smaller list and then doing some math, but you have to be careful that it's big enough that the time is dominated by writing the lines, and not opening and closing the file.

But you should also ask yourself how big the resultant file will be... You may not like what you find. Perhaps you mean 2^16?

Comment: He's apparently trying to brute-force some encryption, so he really meant 2^64, but probably didn't understand the implications of it.

Comment: @SeanWerkema Yes thats correct, and apparently not, thanks for the feedback.